# JQUERY.MB.YTPLAYER is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my site link please help me >>> http://www.fahem.me/fal2u/version3.html

I just ad a background video in header area, but is is not working...

```
<div class="header_area video_area">             
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">                                    
                <div class="header_section">
                    <div id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5_GlAOCHyE', containment:'.header_area',autoPlay:true, loop:true, mute:true, startAt:0, opacity:1, addRaster:false, quality:'default'}">New Video
                    </div>
                    <div id="text_carosule" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>Wellcome To Fal2u</h1>
                            <p>We are professional,talented,Creative digital agency</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
                            <p>We love our works,we live with our works</p>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
                            <p>We love our works,we live with our works</p>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="item">
                            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
                            <p>We love our works,we live with our works</p>
                        </div>                                                                        
                    </div>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about your problem? What doesn't work exactly?

Comment: background video is not working please visit this>>  http://www.fahem.me/fal2u/version3.html

Comment: Please describe what doesn't work like you expect it. If I follow your link above I see a working background video; I can't guess whats wrong with it (Mozilla SeaMonkey on Debian)

Answer (score 1):

I know this maybe a tad late, but just in case someone stumble upon this the issue is the player was never initialized.

Even though you give the `dataProperties` an `autoPlay` attribute it is not going to run. You need add jQuery code that will then initialize the player and begin the autoplay.

In this case he could do:

```
<script>
$(function(){
      jQuery("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues (Video was not playing on mobile) and after spending few hours here is a sample of working code hopping this will help others: 
NOTE: You can get the files from this link 
https://pupunzi.com/test/YTP/

```html
<html>
<head>

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton|Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="../dist/css/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../dist/jquery.mb.YTPlayer.js"></script>

    <script>

        var myPlayer;
        jQuery(function () {
            myPlayer = jQuery("#bgndVideo").YTPlayer({});
            /*
                    myPlayer.YTPApplyFilters({
                        grayscale: 50,
                        sepia: 80,
                        opacity: 30
                    });
            */  
        });
     
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; padding:10px 0;z-index:10">
    <!--7SnmCUwOsts--><!--BsekcY04xvQ--><!--r1xohS2u69E--><!--Fk9EBOOAYiU--><!--sEuXfDtrco8--><!--9d8wWcJLnFI--><!--Fk9EBOOAYiU--><!-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHcAusNO3L4&list=RDEMtvEj6XzR7gbh_QCXSzFudw -->
    <!-- <div id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property="{videoURL:'Fk9EBOOAYiU',containment:'body', showControls:true, autoPlay:true, loop:true, vol:50, mute:true, startAt:10,  stopAt:300, opacity:1, addRaster:true, quality:'large', optimizeDisplay:true, addFilters: {grayscale: 50,sepia: 80,opacity: 30}}">My video</div> -->
    <div id="bgndVideo" class="player" data-property=
    "
    {videoURL:'Fk9EBOOAYiU',containment:'body', showControls:false, 
    autoPlay:true, loop:true, vol:0, mute:true, opacity:1, 
    addRaster:false, quality:'large', optimizeDisplay:true, 
    }
    ">My video</div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```